# How close connection in netcat in a shell script after a pipe?

Tags: bash, netcat

I want to write a script to test my server and I want to be able to connect and disconnect thousands of users in a script that uses `nc`, what I came up with is:

```
echo "Test" | nc localhost <port> &
NCPID=$!
sleep 1
kill -kill $NCPID
```

But I'd like to remove the `sleep 1` and still get the netcat connection closed after "Test" was echoed, how could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `-w` option for netcat:

> -w timeout If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then the connection is silently closed. The -w flag has no
> effect on the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection,
> with or without the -w flag. The default is no timeout.

```
echo "Test" | nc localhost <port> -w 1 &
```